# ListView - how can I properly configure cell's display?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to customize a `ListView` cell's display. Assuming that there's a `ListView` containing objects of a `Person` class and two buttons:

- To add (generate) a new `Person`
- To remove selected `Person`

I'd like to achieve the following goals:

1. When a cell is not selected, it has to show `getBasicView()` of a `Person` which is a `name` field.
2. When a cell is selected, it has to show `getExpandedView()` of a `Person` which is a multiline text `name + "/n" + surname`.

What the problem is?

The code I wrote fills requirements given above but additional bugs appeared:

1. When adding a new `Person` for a blink of an eye the display of cells changes to a `toString()` method which is not implemented (so the user sees `sample.Person@c4f324` alike trash).

[image: Bug no.1]

2. When removing a `Person` from the last cell weird things start to happen. The removed `Person` `name` remains in the cell which **moves two cells down** and because it no longer contains a `Person` object - it cannot be cleared.

[image: Bug no.2]

I tried to add listeners to the cells' `itemProperty` which could check if item is `null`, after what I could set text to `""` but unfortunately it does not work. Does anyone have an idea how can I make my code fully functional?

Providing an SSCCE (assuming that all the files are in the `sample` package):

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

  public void start(Stage stage) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setController(Controller.class);
    try {
      Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <VBox>
        <Button text="Add Person" onAction="#addPerson"/>
        <Button text="Delete Person" onAction="#deletePerson"/>
    </VBox>
    <ListView prefHeight="400" prefWidth="400" fx:id="listView"/>
</HBox>
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Controller {

  @FXML
  private ListView<Person> listView;
  private ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  private String [] names = {"John", "Katherine", "Michael", "August", "Peter"};
  private String [] surnames = {"Jones", "Mayer", "Stevens", "Wayne", "Milton"};

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    initializeListCells();
    initializeList();
  }

  private void initializeList() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
      personList.add(generatePerson());
    }
    listView.setItems(personList);
  }

  private void initializeListCells() {
    listView.setCellFactory(param -> {
      TextFieldListCell<Person> cell = new TextFieldListCell<Person>();
      cell.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handleCellDisplaying(cell));
      cell.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handleCellDisplaying(cell));
      return cell;
    });
  }

  private void handleCellDisplaying(TextFieldListCell<Person> cell) {
    Person person = cell.getItem();
    if (person != null) {
      Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (!cell.isSelected()) {
          cell.setText(person.getBasicView());
        } else {
          cell.setText(person.getExpandedView());
        }
      });
    } else {
      cell.setText("");
    }
  }

  @FXML
  private void addPerson() {
    personList.add(generatePerson());
  }

  @FXML
  private void deletePerson() {
    MultipleSelectionModel<Person> selectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel();
    if (!selectionModel.isEmpty()) {
      int selectedIndex = selectionModel.getSelectedIndex();
      personList.remove(selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  private Person generatePerson() {
    int nameRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,5);
    int surnameRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,5);
    return new Person(names[nameRandom],surnames[surnameRandom]);
  }
}
```

Person.java:

```
package sample;

public class Person {
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  public Person(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }

  public String getBasicView() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getExpandedView() {
    return name + "\n" + surname;
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume 1. in your question should read "when the cell is *not* selected". Do you want these cells to be editable?

Comment: @James_D Nope, just displaying. And yes, *not* selected - my bad.

Comment: So why use a `TextFieldListCell`? That already calls `setText(item.toString())` all over its lifecycle, which is clearly interfering with the functionality you're defining. Just use a plain `ListCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TextFieldListCell` implements the cell lifecycle methods (`updateItem`, etc) and effectively calls `setText(item.toString())` at various points. This is clearly interfering with the behavior you are trying to implement. (For example, the issue with deleting the last cell seems to happen because `setText("")` is called *before* the `TextFieldListCell` resets the text to its previous value. If you use your `Platform.runLater(...)` hack so that it surrounds the complete `if`-`else` clause, then this problem goes away. However...)

If you don't need the cells to be editable, there is no need to use a `TextFieldListCell`: just use a plain `ListCell`. (Also note there is no need for the `Platform.runLater(...)` in the handler for changed item/selected status.)

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Person> listView;
    private ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private String[] names = { "John", "Katherine", "Michael", "August", "Peter" };
    private String[] surnames = { "Jones", "Mayer", "Stevens", "Wayne", "Milton" };

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        initializeListCells();
        initializeList();
    }

    private void initializeList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            personList.add(generatePerson());
        }
        listView.setItems(personList);
    }

    private void initializeListCells() {
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> {
            ListCell<Person> cell = new ListCell<Person>();
            cell.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handleCellDisplaying(cell));
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handleCellDisplaying(cell));
            return cell;
        });
    }

    private void handleCellDisplaying(ListCell<Person> cell) {
        Person person = cell.getItem();
        if (person != null) {
            if (!cell.isSelected()) {
                cell.setText(person.getBasicView());
            } else {
                cell.setText(person.getExpandedView());
            }
        } else {
            cell.setText("");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void addPerson() {
        personList.add(generatePerson());
    }

    @FXML
    private void deletePerson() {
        MultipleSelectionModel<Person> selectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel();
        if (!selectionModel.isEmpty()) {
            int selectedIndex = selectionModel.getSelectedIndex();
            personList.remove(selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    private Person generatePerson() {
        int nameRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5);
        int surnameRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5);
        return new Person(names[nameRandom], surnames[surnameRandom]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you can't reproduce the second bug? Just select the last item and then keep clicking "Delete Person" button.

Comment: @notmyf4ulty Yes, just figured that out. I can reproduce it now. You can actually eliminate that if you put `Platform.runLater(...)` around the whole `if`-`else`, but there's no reason to use `TextFieldListCell`, and if you just use `ListCell` (which never calls `setText()`) you don't need `Platform.runLater()` at all.

Comment: The example is a piece of much more complicated case (the original ``ListView`` is edited from other application threads) so I can't totally remove the ``Platform.runLater(...)`` part. But I worked this out - I overridden ``toString()`` to invoke ``getBasicView()``. Anyway, thanks @James_D, your solution with moving ``Platform.runLater(...)`` worked like a charm.

Comment: The solution is surely to use `ListCell` instead of `TextFieldListCell`. Doesn't that fix it without polluting your `toString()` method, regardless of `Platform.runLater()`?

Comment: Ayyy, you're absolutely right! I forgot to change ``TextFieldListCell`` to ``ListCell`` while initializing the ``cell``.